# R - How do we load a library in a Shiny App so that functions are local, so functions can modify the session specific variable using <<- operator?

Tags: r, namespaces, shiny, package, scoping

**How do we load a library in a Shiny App such that its functions are local to the session, such that the library is loaded for each session**. The reason for that is we have a package XYZ it has function Test, which sets the value of a global variable "sessionVariable" to 2. Now if we source the XYZ directly in shinyServer the sessionVariable is session specific and everything works well. But when we build XYZ into a package and use the library function it looks for the sessionVariable  in R's global environment and not in shinyServer session and it fails. **How can we do something like  source("../R/XYZ.R",local=TRUE) replace it with library(XYZ, local=TRUE)**

The reason we want to do this are

1. sessionVariable has to be a session variable only visible in the server
2. The XYZ package has functions that are all aware of sessionVariable since when XYZ was developed the sessionVariable always was a global variable and we wanted to prevent passing the sessionVariable to each function to prevent overhead.
3. When we use source the sessionVariable acts as pseudo Global as in its specific to server session ( <<- operator still works (within functions in XYZ.R only modifies session specific copy of sessionVariable) and XYZ.R functions work without any problem ***and when we end / exit the shiny app. There is no global sessionVariable in R environment (proving the point its session specific).***
4. Using library seems elegant as package can be a binary build. I understand this is problem of elegant solution rather than a problem with no solution.

**Example using Source**

```
library("shiny") 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
getEnvOf <- function(what, which=rev(sys.parents())) { for (frame in which) if (exists(what, frame=frame, inherits=FALSE)) return(sys.frame(frame)) return(NULL) }
source("../R/XYZ.R",local=TRUE)
sessionVariable <- 1
print(getEnvOf("sessionVariable"))
print (sessionVariable)
testFunc()
print(getEnvOf("testFunc"))
print(sessionVariable)
}
```

in XYZ.R

```
testFunc <-  function()
{
sessionVariable <<- 2
}
```

**Results :**

```
<environment: 0x0000000055138738>
<environment: 0x0000000055138738>
function()
{
.... 
}
<environment: 0x0000000055138738>
```

Results would be 1 2

**Example using library**

But if I binary build XYZ.R

And do this

```
library("shiny") 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
getEnvOf <- function(what, which=rev(sys.parents())) { for (frame in which) if (exists(what, frame=frame, inherits=FALSE)) return(sys.frame(frame)) return(NULL) }
library("XYZ")
sessionVariable <- 1
print(getEnvOf("sessionVariable "))
print (sessionVariable)
testFunc()
print(getEnvOf("testFunc"))
print(sessionVariable)
}
```

**Results :**

```
<environment: 0x0000000055138738>
NULL
function()
{
.... 
}
<environment: namespace:XYZ>
```

*I get 1 and error sessionVariable not found in testFunc*

I am guessing the library loads in Global environment and sessionVariable scope is within shinyServer and hence it doesn't work. Offcourse I can change the line sessionVariable <- 1 to sessionVariable <<- 1 and make sessionVariable global but that's not what I want to do.

**Alternatively I also tried using import::here**

Using third alternate (to source and library) i.e. using import::here("testFunc",.from="XYZ") and checking the env of testFunc using getEnvOf shows the the env of testFunc and sessionVariable is the same

```
library("shiny") 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
library("XYZ")
getEnvOf <- function(what, which=rev(sys.parents())) { for (frame in which) if (exists(what, frame=frame, inherits=FALSE)) return(sys.frame(frame)) return(NULL) }
sessionVariable <- 1
print(getEnvOf("sessionVariable"))
print (sessionVariable)
testFunc()
print(getEnvOf("testFunc"))
print(sessionVariable)
}
```

**Results :**

```
<environment: 0x00000000443d03a0>
<environment: 0x00000000443d03a0>
function () 
{ ...
}
<environment: namespace:XYZ>
```

Which also doesn't work as I get the same error as using library.